# Inline or modal dialog for responsive filters?

Tags: usability, responsive-design, filter

I need to filter a large list of items in a responsive web app. I'm working on two different approaches:

A) Filters open in a modal dialog. In small screens, it would open taking full screen.

B) Inline filters. After clicking "Add filters" button, the content would be pushed down.

I think, option "A" would work better for small devices but option B would be more "natural" for desktop view.

[image: Modal dialog or inline block]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say both the approaches are intriguing but a modal window approach is generally preferred if the set of filters is huge (for eg: On retail store sites)but in your prototype I don't see any need of a modal window,the same can be efficiently achieved through an accordion as you have shown in option B.